# is it ok to use one connectionstring to multiple queries

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

how to optimize this codes, I optimize  my execution error by buying a server ram but I want my codes to be optimize to.... and can I reuse my connection?

i have a `public sub sqlconnect()` which has the codes for my connection

```
sqlcon = new sqlconnection(cstring);
```

can I use sqlconnect to process all the queries below without calling it again? or should I use sqlconnect then just use sqlcon.close()?

you can see below that I use too many sqlconenction...

```vb
Public Class Tracking
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Try
            Dim airbill, branchcode, t_sender, receiver, setpackagetype, getpackagetype, setdestination, getdestination, Setbranchid, getbranchid, settrackstats, dateuploaded As String
            sqlconnect()
            sqltable = New DataTable
            sqladapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AIRBILLS WHERE  AirbillNo='" & txttrackor.Text & "' and TrackingNo = '" & txttrackcode.Text & "'", sqlcon)
            sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)
            settrackstats = sqltable.Rows(0)("TrackingstatusID")
            airbill = sqltable.Rows(0)("AirbillNo")
            branchcode = sqltable.Rows(0)("TrackingNo")
            t_sender = sqltable.Rows(0)("Sender")
            receiver = sqltable.Rows(0)("Addressee")
            setpackagetype = sqltable.Rows(0)("ServiceID")
            Setbranchid = sqltable.Rows(0)("BranchID")
            dateuploaded = sqltable.Rows(0)("DateUploaded")
            Label17.Text = dateuploaded
            'get destination
            If IsDBNull(sqltable.Rows(0)("destinationID")) Then
                getdestination = ""
                Label13.Text = getdestination
            Else
                setdestination = sqltable.Rows(0)("destinationID")
                sqlconnect()
                sqltable = New DataTable
                sqladapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DESTINATION where ID = '" & setdestination & "'", sqlcon)
                sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)
                getdestination = sqltable.Rows(0)("DestinationName")
                Label13.Text = getdestination
                sqlcon.Close()
            End If
            sqlcon.Close()
            'get trackignstatus
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()

            For Each track As DataRow In sqltable.Rows
                sqltable = New DataTable
                sqladapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TRACKINGSTATUS WHERE  ID = '" & settrackstats & "'", sqlcon)
                sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(sqltable.Rows(0)("TrackingStatus"))
            Next

            'get the service name of the tracking
            sqlconnect()
            sqltable = New DataTable
            sqladapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SERVICE where ID = '" & setpackagetype & "'", sqlcon)
            sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)
            getpackagetype = sqltable.Rows(0)("ServiceName")
            sqlcon.Close()

            'get the tracking
            'get branch Name
            sqlconnect()
            sqltable = New DataTable
            sqladapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM BRANCHES where ID = '" & Setbranchid & "'", sqlcon)
            sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)
            getbranchid = sqltable.Rows(0)("BranchName")
            Label15.Text = getbranchid & " Branch"
            sqlcon.Close()

            'get tracking status
            sqlconnect()
            sqltable = New DataTable
            sqladapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TRACKING WHERE  TrackingID='" & txttrackor.Text & "' and TrackingCode = '" & txttrackcode.Text & "'", sqlcon)
            sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)

            For Each tracks As DataRow In sqltable.Rows
                Me.Update()
                settrackstats = tracks.Item("StatusID")
                sqltable = New DataTable
                sqladapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TRACKINGSTATUS WHERE  ID = '" & settrackstats & "'", sqlcon)
                sqladapter.Fill(sqltable)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(sqltable.Rows(0)("TrackingStatus"))
            Next

            Label8.Text = airbill
            Label9.Text = branchcode
            Label10.Text = t_sender
            Label11.Text = receiver
            Label12.Text = getpackagetype
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Label8.Text = ""
            Label9.Text = ""
            Label10.Text = ""
            Label11.Text = ""
            Label12.Text = ""
            Label13.Text = ""
            Label15.Text = ""
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Connection pool at rescue:

They are no performance issues opening and closing connections dinamically, because a **[connection pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)** is handling connection objects. Nice explained on docs:

> A **connection pool** is created for each unique connection string. When a pool is created, multiple connection objects are created and added to the pool so that the minimum pool size requirement is satisfied. Connections are added to the pool as needed, up to the maximum pool size specified (100 is the default). Connections are released back into the pool when they are closed or disposed.

## Single connection:

If I have not convinced you and you use a **single connection** for all operations ( in a kind of singleton class that returns de connection ), may be you should to enable [Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/multiple-active-result-sets-mars):

> Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that allows the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. In previous versions, only one batch could be executed at a time against a single connection. Executing multiple batches with MARS does not imply simultaneous execution of operations.

Set it *on* as a parameter on [string connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Notice**: may be you should to enable MARS anyway, an example is you launch new queries, over same connection, on every iteration of another query.

Comment: Thanks for the link I think I can use it to my next project in my company that I emplyed with.